# MVC 4: View is not rendered with the correct data from a List<> in the Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Having a pretty tricky ASP.NET MVC bug (using MVC4). I've tried to strip down the code so as to make this example as clear as possible

I have a Model

```
//this is the mvc model
public class CustomColumnConfiguration //stripped down to the "problem" property only
{
    public CustomColumnConfiguration()
    {
        Columns = new List<ColumnConfig>();
    }

    public List<ColumnConfig> Columns { get; set; }
}


//MVC model contains a list of these
public class ColumnConfig
{
    public ColumnConfig()
    {
        Name = "";
        Alias = "";
        Order = 0.0;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Alias { get; set; }
    public double Order { get; set; }
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
}
```

Here is a snippet from my razor view

```
<tbody>
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>Column @(i+1)</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Columns[i].Name)</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Columns[i].Alias)</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Columns[i].Order)</td>
        <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Columns[i].UseRange)</td>
        <td><button name="RemoveBtn@(i)" class="btn btn-danger submit-action" type="submit" value="remove-@(i)"><i class="icon-remove icon-white"></i></button></td>
    </tr>
}
</tbody>
//...
@Html.Hidden("Action")
```

The following javascript is responsible for setting the "action" input in my form back to the controller so I know which index to remove:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".submit-action").on("click", function (e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        $("#action").val($this.val());
    });
});
```

GET and POST Controller code:

```
public ActionResult ManageCustomColumns()
{
    CustomColumnConfiguration model = GetConfiguration(); //this works  
        return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]

public ActionResult ManageCustomColumns(CustomColumnConfiguration model)
{
    var action = Request.Form["Action"];
    if (action.Equals("SaveIndexConfiguration", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        this.AlertSuccess("Configuration Saved");
        SetConfiguration(model); //this works
    }
    else if(action.StartsWith("remove",StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        var indexToRemove = int.Parse(action.Split('-')[1]);
        model.Columns.RemoveAt(indexToRemove);
    }
    else if (action.StartsWith("add", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        model.Columns.Insert(0, new ColumnConfig() { Name = "NEW_COLUMN_NAME", Alias = "New Column Alias" });
    }

    return View(model);

}
```

If I have a page with column configs 1, 2, 3, 4. I can click the "remove" button next to column 2 and when debugging the code in VS, I see that the ColumnConfig with name "2" is in fact deleted from the model's Columns property. When debugging the razor, again, the "2" column is gone.

BUT, with 100% consistency in IE and Chrome, the behavior I'm seeing is that the 1,2,3 are still there and it just deletes the last one (4). This is not consistent at all with what I'm seeing in the debugger. I'm not a novice with MVC but this has got to be one of the most magical bugs I've seen.

Does anyone have any idea what could be happening?

**Update**
Furthermore, when I click add, I expect to have another row in my html table with things like "NEW_COLUMN_NAME". It DOES add another row, but it seems to duplicate the last row's data instead of putting the values from my controller.

Again, my controller would say that I have one new ColumnConfig with "NEW_COLUMN_NAME" in it when I debug, but the page that actually gets rendered to the client has the previous ColumnConfig's data in it. This is maddening!

Comment: A quick look - _seems_ you're equating a property with a _position/index_ in a list? When the form is posted, can you  check on the model param (and check if the list is in the "order" you expect)?

Comment: @EdSF Exactly. I'm using an index. When I debug the data that gets POSTed back to the controller the index is in the correct order, and the correct column index is removed. It's just when I return the model, the page renders with the wrong data. Note that when debugging the razor cshtml, the data in the model is still correct.

Comment: If you delete column 2, I hope it's not something as silly as you were expecting it to show 1, 3, 4 (in that order) in the first column of the table.

Comment: When I delete column 2, I expect 1,3,4 to show up, but instead, 1,2,3 get rendered instead. If I remove column 2 again, then 1,2 get rendered. It's like it's always removing from and adding to the last index. At this point I'm just going to do a little hack and store the model in Session and redirect back to my GET controller method. Then make that smart enough to use the session model if it's not null. Then when I save the model on the POST controller, I'll null out the session model.

Comment: @howcheng Anyway, I'll +1 your answer because you were absolutely correct on your assumptions, before I updated my answer to show that I had already accounted for your suggestions. It may still be a helpful nugget for someone else.

Comment: I'm going to try upgrading to MVC 5 and see if that affects anything

Comment: `<td>Column @(i+1)</td>` is always going to show the numbers in incremental order. You'll never get 1, 3, 4 with that.

Comment: right, I want that. It will show 1,2,3,4, etc, but the actual values bound to the model like Name, Alias, Order Etc, are incorrect

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old post but I had the same problem with a .RemoveAt() call. Found a solution. I added this code before my .RemoveAt() call.

```
ModelState.Clear();
```

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Is ModelState an MVC thing that gets hauled around?

Comment: Yeah, it exists as an object that can be accessed by anything that implements the Controller class. It represents all the values that were posted to the server. So what that page podyed and what you're returning isn't lining up and the pages are using the ModelState over the returned values.

Comment: Hmm. Good thought. I wouldn't be surprised at all if this is the right answer considering all of the black box features MVC has. Thanks for posting this! I'll see if I can use this in place of the workaround that I did and accept your answer if it works.

Comment: Hours of trouble shooting resolved with a single line. Obvious when you know the answer. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

1. You have `<form>` tags somewhere that you didn't show us.
2. Your form does a POST to the `ManageCustomColumns` action.

Note that you are trying to determine which column config to remove based on the value of `Request.Form["Action"]`. Where is this form field in your HTML? Note also that your button with the value of `remove-1` is called `RemoveBtn1`, so the result is that the value you want is going to be in `Request.Form["RemoveBtn1"]`. You probably need a hidden form field called "Action" and use Javascript on the button click to populate that field with the button value.

Comment: Yes, I have a razor `using` code block for the form that does a POST. I also have a hidden input for 'action' (edited question to show this)

Comment: `@Html.Hidden` with just one parameter only sets the name of the field, not the ID, but your Javascript is looking for that element by ID. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.web.mvc.html.htmlhelperextensions.hidden%28v=vs.118%29.aspx for the documentation.

Comment: I just inspected the input that `Html.Hidden` generated. It's `<input id="Action" name="Action" type="hidden" value="" />`

Comment: Anyway, like I was saying - my controller code works perfectly. I get exactly what I expect from Request.Form["Action"]. It's just rendering with the wrong for some reason.